# Center button inside bootstrap <pre>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pre

I have done a good bit of searching and even tried modifing the bootstrap css file for .btn and `<pre>` but I cannot figure out how to get this thing centered

```
<pre style="margin: 0 auto 10px;max-:36px;">
Currentpassword
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="float: right;margin: 0 auto;">Button</button>
</pre>
```

I'm sure it's something simple. I posted an image below, thank you to anyone that responds!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean horizontally centered, you can add `text-align:center` to the `pre` tag.

```
<pre style="text-align: center">
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
</pre>
```

Comment: I tested this and that centers the text however if you see the picture I have the button seems to be offset from vertical alignment. It doesn't do this when I do not have a alignment style on the button however when I align my button to the right it off center.